# How can I get the current date in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i am new with .net core so what i done is creating article with title, date, description, image

this is my model

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

    public DateTime ArticleDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ArticleDescriotion { get; set; }
    public string ArticleImage { get; set; }
}
```

this is the controller

```
public IActionResult CreateArticle()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult CreateArticle(Article article)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Articales.Add(article);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(article);
}
```

this is the view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ArticleDate" class="col-md-4 control-label" ></label>
     <input asp-for="ArticleDate" class="form-control">
</div>
```

I can enter the date manually and it works fine, but I want it to load the current date automatically.

Comment: So what specifically are you having issue with?

Comment: Be clear as to which time you want. Is this the current time on the server that is generating the webpage or this this the current time of the user that is viewing the webpage?

Comment: i do not have issue as error, as of now i enter the date manually but i want it get the current date (date.now )automatically appear in the label and when click create button it take the date and inserted in DB

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the view to load with the current DateTime, you could use this:

```
public class Article
{
    ... your current code

    public Article()
    {
        ArticleDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Or, you could pass the model to the view directly:

```
public IActionResult CreateArticle()
{
    var model = new Article { ArticleDate = DateTime.Now };
    return View(model);
}
```

Notice that by using `DateTime.Now`, the date might not be the date of the client visiting the page (due to time-zones).  If your users and the server are all in the same timezone, this would be just fine.
You could use `DateTime.UtcNow` if you want the UTC date instead of the date of the server running the application, but that does not always help. You would need to load the date in the client (i.e through JavaScript) if you want to display the actual date for every client.

I will suggest you, however, to **not** use entities (a class that represent a table) directly. Look up on using ViewModels.

---

With your update I see what the problem is. The `LabelTagHelper` (what enables you to use `asp-for` in a `<label>`) renders the description of the property, not its value. This is because labels are meant for describing the content that follows them, not their content.

Comment: You probably want the label to be "Article Date" and the input to display the actual date.

Comment: Note that `DateTime.Now` will use the time zone of the server. That's almost *always* a bad idea.

Comment: @SteveWright Sorry, I don't understand why you are saying that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I'm fully aware of that, thanks. Mentioned in the update

Comment: i use the second method u provide and when create breakpoint i see the current date of today but the problem is it is now show in the label when page loads and also after click create button its is not store the date of today so what i got from database is 01/01/0001

Comment: i fix it, thank you @Camilo Terevinto, your answer help me a lot, i used first method and then in the label i so this <label asp-for="ArticleDate" class="col-md-4 control-label">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.ArticleDate)</label> so as of now it work perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.UtcNow to get the current date and time on the current computer, expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)

Comment: where is should use DateTime.now, in the controller, or view or model ??? and how use it

Answer (score 0):

the model

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

    public DateTime ArticleDate { get; set; }
    public Article()
    {
        ArticleDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ArticleDescriotion { get; set; }
    public string ArticleImage { get; set; }
}
```

the view

```
  <label asp-for="ArticleDate" class="col-md-4 control-label">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.ArticleDate)</label>
```

this is work with me perfectly thank everyone specially for @Camilo Terevinto

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling to do this and thought I would post this answer as I just figured it out and I couldn't get any of the other methods to work.

If using the standard ASP.NET Identity and creating a custom data model then you can override the default values in the OnPostAsync method of the page model:

```
//Override values for created by and date
Blog.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
Blog.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Defining the values here rather than on the form means it is not possible for people to over post the data.

So the method now looks like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    //Override values for created by and date
    Blog.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    Blog.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

    _context.Blogs.Add(Blog);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Then you can remove these from the form on the page (if you have set the field as required in your data model then it must remain on the form as a hidden field with a value assigned otherwise the form will not submit - I just set the value to X as am overriding it anyway):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input asp-for="Blog.CreatedBy" class="form-control" value="X" hidden />
    <span asp-validation-for="Blog.CreatedBy" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps others.

Robin